# How to perform calculation given multiple types of numbers?

Tags: scala

I have some numbers list that I go through it, and doing a simple calculation to for two numbers:

I have numberA and numberB, and the calculation im doing is:

```
val res = (numberA/numberB) * 100
```

now, I dont know what type is the number, but I know it could be float (with 2 nums after the dot) or integer...

so I want to know what is the syntax in scala to calculate it?

currently I have:

```
val num1 = (vatReclaimed.toInt/vatPaid.toInt) * 100
```

but its obviously dont work, and I cannot really use toInt i guess since I dont know the type...

whats important to me that the res will hold the right answer, so if its 2.3 * 4 the res will hold 9.2

thanksss!

Comment: is it okay to have resulting type as float all the time? if so, it will be as simple as `.toFloat` + `.toFloat`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do not know the type only, that is a number, you probably have to work with `Numeric`. With numeric you can convert any numeric value to `Double, Float, Int or Long`. For precision I would recommend `Double`:

```
def calc[A : Numeric, B : Numeric](a: A, b: B): Double = (a.toDouble / b.toDouble) * 100
```

Comment: Note that if you are going to be comparing exact things (e.g. 0.3 == 0.1 + 0.2), Double is inexact and so won't be exactly right.  For the same reason, it's generally not a good idea for financial calculations.  ("Two nums after the dot" makes me think of cents.)